# How to add Environment Variables in vite.config.js for a React Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, vite, vite-reactjs

How can I add Environment Variables in Vite React Project in the vite.config.js file

I wanted to add the proxy_url in the .env file and add it to the environment when deploying.
Please have a look below!

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

const proxy_url = "http://localhost:5000/";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: proxy_url,
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^/api/, ""),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Some blogs and answers on StackOverflow but they were resolving the same issue for Vue.
Those didn't work for me in my Vite-React Project!

Answer (score 7):

you can use it in this way:

install "cross-env" package and config vite

```js
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '')

  return {
    define: {
      __APP_ENV__: env.APP_ENV,
    },

    // rest of Vite config
  }
}
```

to use in your code you can do in this way:

```js
import.meta.env.VariableName
```

update:
according to Vite [documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files), environment variables should start with `VITE_` prefix to get known

for example in .env file:

`VITE_BASE_API_URL=http://localhost:5000`

to use it :

```js
import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_API_URL
```

Comment: It's giving Can't read property of undefined reading proxy

Answer (score 3):

This will work. Get a .env file and than make your vite.config.js file like this

```
import {defineConfig, loadEnv} from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig(({mode}) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd());

  return {
    plugins: [react()],
    build: {
      outDir: "./wwwroot/app/",
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    server: {
      port: env.VITE_PORT,
    },
  };
});
```

This is my .env file. You dont have to install anything extra

```
VITE_PORT=3000
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm trying to target the PROXY_URL (for Backend) but don't want to expose it on the Code (use as env variable) and not the PORT on which the Application should run :(

Answer (score 1):

```
 import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'
 import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

   export default defineConfig(({mode})=>{
 const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd());

return{
plugins: [react()],
build:{
   outDir:"./wwwroot/app/", sourcemap:true
 },
  server: {

proxy: {
  "^/api": {
    target:env.VITE_PORT,
    
    changeOrigin: true,
    secure: false,
    withCredentials: true,
    rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ``),
  },   
   
},
   port:4000
 }
}
})
```

Than, you can call it by api

```
  async fetchdata(){
     
  await  axios.get(`/api/${mainPage}`,{
 
 }
).then(response=>{})
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly same issue and found a solution:

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd());

  const API_URL = `${env.VITE_API_URL ?? 'http://localhost:3000'}`;
  //or leave it empty const API_URL = `${env.VITE_API_URL ?? ''}`;

  return {
    server: {
      proxy: {
        '/api': {
          target: API_URL,
          changeOrigin: true,
          rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
        },
      },
    },
    plugins: [react()],
  };
});
```

In .env

```
VITE_API_URL=https://your-api-url.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who is **using Vite 4.0** and `process.env = { ...process.env, ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd()) };` **is not working** for you **try this**:

First Install `dotenv` using `yarn add dotenv`. Then go to your `vite.config.js` file write these:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

dotenv.config();

console.log("hello", process.env.VITE_HOMEPAGE_URL) //when you run the frontend using yarn dev you will be able to see this on you cmd to know this works! :D

export default defineConfig({
  base: process.env.VITE_HOMEPAGE_URL,
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

Your environment variable file `.env` should look something like this:

```
VITE_HOMEPAGE_URL=https://abc.something.com/home/
```

If you face linter error like `process is not defined` go to your `.eslintrc.cjs` file and add `node: true` inside the `env`. So it will look something like below

```
module.exports = {
  env: { browser: true, es2020: true, node: true },
  //...other settings
}
```