# Vite TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'VITE_YOUTUBE_API_KEY')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, backend, vite

I'm getting this error when trying to read an Env Variable from the .env file.

Things to know: my .env is in the root directory, the variable is prefixed by **VITE_**, and I'm trying to import it doing
`const apiKey = import.meta.env.VITE_YOUTUBE_API_KEY;`

I've scoured the web, but most of the answers were either *"use VITE prefix"* or *"use import.meta.env"*. I also tried using **loadEnv** like this https://vitejs.dev/config/#using-environment-variables-in-config, but I get "process is not defined" at `const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '')`.

Here's my .env (I've also tried removing the quotes from the variables, same thing):

```js
MONGODB_URI="mongodb+srv://USER:PASS@cluster0.f2tb4tn.mongodb.net/tutorialsApp?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0"
JWT_SECRET="JWT_SECRET"
VITE_YOUTUBE_API_KEY="YOUTUBE_API_KEY"
VITE_CHANNEL_ID="CHANNEL_ID"
VITE_CLIENT_ID="CLIENT_ID"
```

Edit: here's my vite.config.js:

```js
import { transformWithEsbuild, defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// Access import.meta.env directly
const appEnv = import.meta.env;

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    {
      name: "treat-js-files-as-jsx",
      async transform(code, id) {
        if (!id.match(/src\/.*\.js$/)) return null;

        return transformWithEsbuild(code, id, {
          loader: "jsx",
          jsx: "automatic",
        });
      },
    },
    react(),
  ],
  optimizeDeps: {
    force: true,
    esbuildOptions: {
      loader: {
        ".js": "jsx",
      },
    },
  },
  define: {
    __APP_ENV__: JSON.stringify(appEnv),
  },
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you calling the env from browser environment or node environment ? And why all your ```.env``` variables value use double quote ? Can i see your vite config ?

Comment: I'm calling it from a backend file using import.meta.env, I'm not sure if that's a browser or a Node environment. The variables have quotes because that's how I left them right now, but as I said, I also tried removing the quotes and it didn't change anything. I'll edit and post my vite.config.js!

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75265212/5292901